# Python destructor for failed constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following example class in Python:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

    def __del__(self):
        if self._obj:
            print(self._obj)
```

in the test suite, I would want to check that an exception is thrown when the constructor is called with no arguments, i.e.:

```
c = MyClass()
```

With this, I get the expected exception from the constructor:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../example.py", line 9, in <module>
    c = MyClass()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'
```

However, the destructor also fails with the message:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method MyClass.__del__ of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000023D1211CD30>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../example.py", line 6, in __del__
    if self._obj:
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '_obj'
```

Presumably, this is because the constructor is never called since there is an argument missing, so the attributes are never created.

What's the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Do you have a less abstract example? If you really want to be safe, use `getattr` or `try` the attribute access.

Comment: Python does not have destructors.  It does have finalizers.  Usually, the correct way to do things is to avoid using them altogether.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the exception generated in `__del__` is being ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if the attribute is actually set, *or* provide a default by also making it a class attribute.

For example, setting a class attribute makes your current code work:

```
class MyClass:
    _obj = None  # class attribute

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

    def __del__(self):
        if self._obj:
            print(self._obj)
```

or use `getattr()` with a default:

```
def __del__(self):
    if getattr(self, '_obj', None):
        print(self._obj)
```

The 3rd argument is returned if the attribute isn't present.

Comment: Does this mean that the `self._obj = obj` line replaces the class attribute with an instance one?

Comment: Not replaces, no. The instance attribute *masks* the class attribute as Python looks up attributes first on the instance, then the class, then base classes.

Comment: Ah, OK. That makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: I think I prefer the `getattr` approach. Although I think I've figured how to do what I was intending with context managers and `contextlib.ExitStack`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class-property:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _obj = None

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

    def __del__(self):
        if self._obj:
            print(self._obj)
```

This way, there is always a default (falsy) value (if the instance lookup fails, the class lookup will succeed).

With that said, `__del__` in python is sort of a black sheep.  Generally the advice is "don't use it" for a number of reasons.  Context managers are often a slightly more explicit substitute (though they don't cover all use cases).